# How to search for users in Global Catalog within AD forest with multiple trees

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, userprincipal

I have the following AD forest with two trees:

1. Domain1. Has two child domains Domain2 and Domain3
2. Domain4. Doesn't have child domains.

DNS name of the Domain1 is *domain1.local*. DNS name of the Domain4 is *domain4.local*.

In each domain there is a domain controller with Global Catalog enabled.

I'm trying to get UserPrincipal for the user from Domain 4 by its SID. The program runs from a machine in Domain2.

I use the following code:

```
// Running on some machine from Domain2
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
    "dc2.domain2.domain1.local:3268", // Using Global Catalog port and local domain controller
    "DC=domain1, DC=local", // I guess the problem is here
    "domain1\\super-admin", // User has all necessary rights across all domains 
    "password");

UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "SID-OF-A-USER-FROM-DOMAIN-4");
```

In my case principal is null (the user was not found).

Searching within one tree (domain1 and its children) works fine with the code snippet above, but I have no idea how to modify the container parameter of the PrincipalContext constructor to really enable forest-wide searches.

Initially I thought that "DC=domain1, DC=local" points to the forest root, but it seems I have  misunderstanding here.

And I know that if I change the container path to "DC=domain4, DC=local" then the search will work, but only for users in domain4.

But I really need such a container path that will point to the entire forest, so I could search for users from any domain within a forest using the same PrincipalContext.

Any help is appreciated, especially if anyone could clarify if my requirements are achievable.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue right now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181591/an-alternate-in-principlecontext-for-looking-up-user-in-a-forest

Answer (score 6):

We could not find any other solution except switching to DirectorySearcher. So it appears that PrincipalContext class doesn't fully support searching in the whole forest.

I cannot say this solution is ideal. I guess it can be tuned for better performance. But we are really disappointed it could not be done using PrincipalContext.

Here is the rough idea how our code works now:

```
...

// Here is a list of SIDs of users we want to find (initialized somewhere above)
List<string> userSids;

// List of sample results.
List<string> loadedUsers = new List<string>();

using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("GC://dc2.domain2.domain1.local")))
{
    StringBuilder filterStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Just create a single LDAP query for all user SIDs
    filterStringBuilder.Append("(&(objectClass=user)(|");
    foreach (string userSid in users)
    {
        filterStringBuilder.AppendFormat("({0}={1})", "objectSid", userSid);
    }

    filterStringBuilder.Append("))");

    searcher.PageSize = 1000; // Very important to have it here. Otherwise you'll get only 1000 at all. Please refere to DirectorySearcher documentation

    searcher.Filter = filterStringBuilder.ToString();

    // We do not want to go beyond GC
    searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.None;

    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(
        new[] { "DistinguishedName" });

    SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();

    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results)
    {
        string distinguishedName = searchResult.Properties["DistinguishedName"][0].ToString();
        loadedUsers.Add(distinguishedName);
    }
}

...
```

Comment: I had similar requirement as yours and this worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373837/how-to-search-global-catalog-whole-forest-using-principalcontext/38376593#38376593