# Validating active directory user using a user between two sub domains

Tags: c#, active-directory, subdomain

I have the following scenario:

Domain **company.com** has two subdomains: ***a.company.com*** and ***b.company.com***. The users are in both subdomains (mixed) but the technical user is only in ***a.company.com*** and has permissions on ***b.company.com*** as well as the domains are trusted.

When I try to generate a PrincipleContext as:

```
var oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "b.company.com", null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing, "TechnicalUserName", "TechnicalUserPassword");
```

I get message that the user "TechnicalUserName" does not exists in "**b**.company.com". The message is okay but the user "TechnicalUserName" exist in "**a**.company.com" and has full privileges over "**b**.company.com"

The reason I have a technical user for creating PrincipleContext is because that context will be privileged to reset, change, and unlock other user active directory accounts.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

How about passing "TechnicalUserName@a.company.com" instead of just "TechnicalUserName"?

Comment: Fully qualified name doesn't help. I forgot to point that out.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694799/how-to-search-for-users-in-global-catalog-within-ad-forest-with-multiple-trees) post PrincipalContext does not support cross forest lookups and you'll need to use a DirectoryEntry/DirectorySearcher instead.