# How to search Global Catalog (whole forest) using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry, account-management

```
 myUserList AppUsers = new myUserList();    
 using (PrincipalContext pcxt = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
            {
                UserPrincipal User = new UserPrincipal(pcxt);
                User.EmailAddress = emailString;

                PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(User);
                foreach (var principal in srch.FindAll())
                {
                    var p = (UserPrincipal)principal;
                    myUserRow User = AppUsers.NewUsersRow();
                    User.FirstName = p.GivenName;
                    User.LastName = p.Surname;
                    User.Email = p.EmailAddress;
                    AppUsers.AddUsersRow(User);

                }
            }
```

I have code similar to the above that searches Active Directory for user information using PrincipalContext class.

As you can see i pass in the domainName during the search. 
How can i modify this peace of code to instead search the entire forest (i.e Global Catalog) but still use the PrincipalContext class?

I can't seem to find a working example that uses PrincipalContext class to do a Global Catalog search.

I have seen this post [How to search for users in Global Catalog within AD forest with multiple trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694799/how-to-search-for-users-in-global-catalog-within-ad-forest-with-multiple-trees) but the poster seems to suggest that they did not find a solution that uses PrincipalContext class, they had to switch back to DirectorySearcher.

Is there any PrincipalContext class code sample that demonstrates searching in the whole forest (Global Catalog)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, i got it working. I just had to change my code like below.

```
 myUserList AppUsers = new myUserList();    
 using (PrincipalContext pcxt = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,  "my-global-catalogue-server.subdomain.domain.com:port", "DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com"))
            {
                UserPrincipal User = new UserPrincipal(pcxt);
                User.EmailAddress = emailString;

                PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(User);
                foreach (var principal in srch.FindAll())
                {
                    var p = (UserPrincipal)principal;
                    myUserRow User = AppUsers.NewUsersRow();
                    User.FirstName = p.GivenName;
                    User.LastName = p.Surname;
                    User.Email = p.EmailAddress;
                    AppUsers.AddUsersRow(User);

                }
            }
```